# Understanding ptsize options in article.cls

Tags: fontsize, article, class-options

When the `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` class options are used with the standard LaTeX classes everything works as expected.

Except, if I put two of them in the class' options I would expect the last given to "win" but instead the highest value wins.

MWE: the following will be typeset using 12pt fonts:

```
\documentclass[12pt,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla
\end{document}
```

In `article.cls` the `1xpt` options renew the macro `\@ptsize` so I would expect that the last `10pt` option would set `\@ptsize` to 0.
Indeed, the class sets `10pt` as default using `\ExecuteOptions`, allowing you to overwrite the default with a different choice.

Why is that? What am I getting wrong?

Comment: If you add `tracingmacros=1` above documentclass, the log-file reveals an option clash when loading the class.

Comment: @Johannes_B er, no:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, read a bit further and noticed that i was talking nonsense :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`article` uses `\ProcessOptions` not `\ProcessOptions*` so options are processed in the order they are declared in the class, and the order of options in the argument is not used.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. So in particular, if I want to write a class based on `article` which sets the default to `12pt` but allows to overwrite that with its options I have to handle those options myself (basically copying and pasting `article`'s defs), correct?

Comment: @Bordaigorl probably that's easiest, yes

Comment: right, and the complication is that I cannot just redefine `\@ptsize` in my options because `\@ptsize` is defined in `article.cls` which is not yet executed. So I will just store the choice in a custom macro and pass that with `\PassOptionToClass` after `\ProcessOptions` and before `\LoadClass{article}` (just if anyone is interested)